# jquery scrolltop function on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used scrolltop function to scroll to top on click of a button but it is not working?

** *jquery* ********

```
jQuery('.scroll').click(function () 
{
  jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: '#fields2' }, 'slow');

    return false;

   });
```

******* *html code* *******

```
  <div id="fields2"> 
      ..............
 ...............

       <input class="send_btn scroll" type="button" value="back"/>
      </div>
```

Comment: try `scrollTop: $('#fields2').offset().top`

Answer (score 1):

Just ask yourself : **scrollTop is a property that indicate the distance from the top of the document, in pixels**.

There, you ask jQuery to animate the scrollTop to "#fields2", which is a string.

So, first, I guess you try to retrieve the distance of element #fields2 from top ?

This way : `$('#fields2').offset().top`

```
jQuery('.scroll, .send_btn').click(function (e) 
{
 e.preventDefault(); 
 var dest = $('#fields2').offset().top;
 jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop:  dest }, 'slow');

 // If you need to submit a form, with an input like : <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Submit"/>
 if(jQuery(this).hasClass('send_btn')) { // check if you've clicked on .send_btn
    $(this).parents('#myForm').submit(); // submit the form.
 }


});
```

Note : I replaced return false by e.preventDefault(). return false is not standard way to stop fire events.

Edit :
As e.preventDefault(); stops the events on the element, you must manually submit the form with jQuery, as seen in the code above.

Comment: It worked fine so thank you everybody. There is also a submit button <input class="send_btn" type="submit" value="Register"/> which should also submit the form and scroll to #fields2. If i give scroll class for the button the submit functionality is not working.

Comment: Edited the answer with a solution to your new problem.

Comment: @mujtaba: If this answer resolved your issue, please don't forget to mark your question it as answered by checking the checkmark before the answer.

Answer (score 0):

***.offset()*** returns the coordinates of an element relative to the document, and top param will give you the element's distance in pixels along the y-axis:

```
jQuery('.scroll').click(function () 
{
  jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop:  $('#fields2').offset().top }, 'slow');

    return false;

   });
```